Alternative methods to capture Read actions in Azure activity log
Based on the documentation, it appears "read" actions are not visible in Azure Activity log:
"Entries in the Activity Log are typically a result of changes (create, update or delete operations) or an action having been initiated. Operations focused on reading details of a resource are not typically captured." [emphasis mine]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log
Is there someplace we can go to see the read operations performed too ? - this is to satisfy the compliance requirements


Alternative methods to capture Read actions in Azure activity log

Azure Activity by default supports Write, Delete, or Action operations. The same operations will be shown even if you export the activity logs to a Log Analytics workspace, follow MS Doc for more details.

To check the resource read activities, you need to enable the 'Read' category. Once enabled, any read operations on the resource (e.g., Storage) will be logged and can be queried in the Log Analytics Workspace.

LAW output
StorageBlobLogs



Thanks for taking the time to answer the question. I was looking for a functionality similar to Cloudtrail in AWS which logs all activities (read, create or modify actions globally). Based on your answer above, in Azure, this is dependent on the resource creator to configure read events logging (or use automation to turn it on). Is that understanding correct ?

Yes, to monitor read operations, you need to enable read operations inside the resource. Automation is not required to turn it on.
